# How can I reduce table row height?

Tags: tables, spacing

I use the following code to render a table in LaTeX. But the problem is that the  default row height is too big for me. I want to be able to specify the row height. How can i do it?

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  File  & size \\ \hline
       hello_world & 1mb\\  \hline
       helloworld2 kB & 64kb \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Check out the [tabls package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabls)!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One option could be using a modified `\arraystretch`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  File  & size \\ \hline
       hello\_world & 1mb \\  \hline
       helloworld2 kB & 64kb \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}% Tighter
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  File  & size \\ \hline
       hello\_world & 1mb \\  \hline
       helloworld2 kB & 64kb \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Wider
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  File  & size \\ \hline
       hello\_world & 1mb \\  \hline
       helloworld2 kB & 64kb \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Also see [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables) for more options on horizontal and vertical padding.

---

For centered horizontal alignment of the columns, you could use the column specifier `c` (which will default to a natural-width column) or use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{<len>}`. For centered vertical alignment of the columns, you could use the column specifier `m{<len>}`. For both, use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{<len>}`. The last two settings require the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  File  & size \\ \hline
       hello\_world & 1mb \\  \hline
       helloworld2 kB & 64kb \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}% Tighter
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  File  & size \\ \hline
       hello\_world & 1mb \\  \hline
       helloworld2 kB & 64kb \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Wider
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  File  & size \\ \hline
       hello\_world & 1mb \\  \hline
       helloworld2 kB & 64kb \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```