# How to make a row in a table shorter?

Tags: tables, height

I have a row of a table (tabular) that has small text (tiny). I would like to make this (first) row shorter, either automatically (automatic height) o̶r̶ ̶m̶a̶n̶u̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶(̶s̶e̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶o̶n̶-̶d̶e̶f̶a̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶h̶e̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶t̶i̶c̶u̶l̶a̶r̶ ̶r̶o̶w̶)̶.̶

I tried different tricks (like using `\\[shift]`) with no success.

MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
{|c|c|c|c|}
{\tiny0}&{\tiny1}&{\tiny2}&{\tiny3}\\[-1mm]
\hline 0 & 4.94066e-323 & 22 & 9.78381e+199\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

A simple solution using `tabular` is preferred but elegant solutions using `pgfplotstables` is also welcomed; specially since I have in mind the enumeration of columns (and eventually of rows).

Note that similar questions, like [How can I reduce table row height?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35515/how-can-i-reduce-table-row-height) deal with *uniform* row heights adjustments.

Comment: Have you tried simply renewing `\arraystretch` inside the `tabular` environment?

Comment: Related: [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)

Comment: @JosephR. it doesn't do what is expected.

Comment: @Wernet: the code posted there doesn't seem to make the row thinner than one text-line height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: since there is default `rowsep` for a `tblr` table, you are free to set `stretch=0` to remove the strut.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|c|c|c|c|},
  hlines,
  row{1} = {font=\tiny},
  stretch = 0,
}
  0 & 1            & 2  & 3            \\
  0 & 4.94066e-323 & 22 & 9.78381e+199 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although these needs to use a different package, it seems to be the most elegant solution of all.

Answer (score 23):

LaTeX adds struts inside the table rows/cells. Each update of the font size/`\baselineskip` (`\size@update`) sets `\strutbox` (a box with height `0.7\baselineskip` and depth `0.3\baselineskip`. At the start of a `tabular`/`array` the box `\@arstrutbox` is set that uses the current `\strutbox` and scales it with factor `\arraystretch`.

The following example defines `\setarstrut{...}` that sets the table strut before the next row:

- The argument allows font size commands, in the example: `\tiny`. Alternatively `\arraystretch` can be changed:

  ```
  \setarstrut{\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.5}}%
  ```
- Internally `\nolign` is used. Therefore `\setarstrut` must be at the start of the row.
  Otherwise it would be to late to set smaller struts anyway.
- The old strutbox is remembered in `\saved@arstrutbox`.
- Small disadvantage is the global settings of the strut box to skip the grouping levels.
  Thus some care is needed, if the table is nested inside another table.

Macro `\saved@arstrutbox` restores the saved strut box.

Example file:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\saved@arstrutbox
\newcommand*{\setarstrut}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \global\setbox\saved@arstrutbox\copy\@arstrutbox
      #1%
      \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{%
        \vrule \@height\arraystretch\ht\strutbox
               \@depth\arraystretch \dp\strutbox
               \@width\z@
      }%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\restorearstrut}{%
  \noalign{%
    \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\copy\saved@arstrutbox
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \setarstrut{\tiny}%
    {\tiny0}&{\tiny1}&{\tiny2}&{\tiny3}\\
    \restorearstrut
    \hline
    0 & 4.94066e-323 & 22 & 9.78381e+199\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Incredible, absolutely incredible.

Comment: Perfect results. But it looks like the `tabular` is not made for this. I'll take a look at `pgfplotstable` to see if it is easier.

Comment: This is marvelous, It helped me with reducing the spacing of "blocks" of a tabular environment. Instead of leaving a full blank line, I inserted a `\tiny` blank line.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't pretty, but it works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settoheight{\mylen}{\tiny 1}
\newcommand{\myheading}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-\mylen}{\tiny #1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
{|c|c|c|c|}
\myheading{0} & \myheading{1} & \myheading{2} & \myheading{3} \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\mylen]
\hline 0 & 4.94066e-323 & 22 & 9.78381e+199 \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This assumes you'll only use similar-height elements in the first row (using the length `\mylen` set to the height of `{\tiny 1}`).

Comment: +1. It looks too cumbersome, is there an automatic way?

Comment: Note that this will cause artifacts in some viewers (evince), and if the "short" row is the last, the vertical lines continue below the table (i.e. they are drawn the same height, it's just the next row that is moved up and covers them).

Answer (score 10):

Given the complexity of the LaTeX solution, I have no option but to post a ConTeXt solution ;-)

Like LaTeX, ConTeXt also inserts a `\strut` in each row of a table. However, rather than fighting the strut, we can simply ask ConTeXt not to add the strut by saying `strut=no`.

```
\startsetups table:size
  \setupTABLE[row][1][style=\tfxx, strut=no]
  \setupTABLE[align=middle]
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTABLE[setups={table:size}]
  \NC 0 \NC 1 \NC 2 \NC 3 \NC \NR
  \NC 0 \NC 4.94066e-323 \NC 22 \NC 9.78381e+199  \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I never used ConTeXt, but I see it here and there really doing things that LaTeX has a hard time doing. Why is ConTeXt so powerful and yet it has an unpleasant syntax (personal opinion).

Comment: Just curious. What do you find unpleasant about ConTeXt's syntax? To me, ConTeXt's syntax is one of its nicer parts.

Comment: not to start a language war but since you ask. This is all personal taste and even can sound silly. All taken from you own example: 1) \star* \stop* blocks don't separate the environment name from the fact that they start or end (\begin{*}\end{*} looks more structured, 2) mixed lower-capital case 'startTABLE', 3) \NC, a command to separate columns? '&' looks more elegant. See, it is all taste.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand your point of view, but, as you say, it is matter of personal taste. FWIW, you can use `\start[...]` and `\stop[...]` if you prefer. Mixed lower case for tables is because ConTeXt already has `\starttable` and `\starttabular`, and `\startlinetable`, so after a while you just run out of names;). Most environments are lower case. `\NC` is a conscious design decision. ConTeXt tends to avoid exposing low level TeX primitives: there were even discussion about getting rid of `$`! See http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/?p=767 for my view on this.