# Row Padding, Row by Row

Tags: tables

Here's my MWE that is almost right... except for the excess padding in the top row which I would like to reduce to 0.2cm. The rest, I'd like to keep at 1.5cm.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

{
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5cm} 

\begin{tabularx}{8cm}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|X|}  \hline

Top Left & Top Middle & Top Right \\ [0.2cm] \hline

Bottom Left & Bottom Middle & Bottom Right \\ [0.2cm] \hline

\end{tabularx}
}

\end{document}
```

[This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables) shows how to specify the one amount of vertical padding above the cells for ALL rows in a table. But what if the rows need different amounts? (I am making worksheets on which students will be writing in pencil.)

P.S. This is my first, or one of my first ever posts on StackExchange. I'm also a LaTeX newb. If there's a better way to pose questions, please let me know and I will edit this post. Thanks!

Comment: I need the `\hline` as that those lines will show up in my worksheets and be part of how my students know where to write answers. I also don't know how I could easily see the vertical padding without them. I do not need the `\booktabs` package for the MWE, though, so I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

An easy, but manual solution, to this problem would be to reduce the value defined in `\extrarowheight` to 0.2cm and manually add an empty row of 1.1cm (1.1cm + 2 * 0.2cm = 1.5cm) above each row for which a top padding of 1.5cm is desired.

This approach has some limitations however. Because there is a minimum height a table row can have by default (see [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables/76093#76093)), the minimal padding that it is possible to add with this approach is limited by the `\baselineskip`. It is, however, possible to reduce this value as described here: [How to make a row in a table shorter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84524/how-to-make-a-row-in-a-table-shorter/84536#84536).

Below is a MWE that shows how it can be done:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering  
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.2cm}  
    \begin{tabularx}{8cm}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|X|} \hline

        Top Left & Top Middle & Top Right \\[0.2cm] \hline
        && \\[1.1cm]
        Middle Left & Middle & Middle Right \\[0.2cm] \hline
        && \\[1.1cm]
        Bottom Left & Bottom Middle & Bottom Right \\[0.2cm] \hline

    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

**Update (2015-07-27):**

Below is an updated solution derived from the macro presented at: [How to make a row in a table shorter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84524/how-to-make-a-row-in-a-table-shorter/84536#84536). It consists in a new command, which allows to add an extra custom row padding of a given height on a row by row basis.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Modified from :
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84524/
% how-to-make-a-row-in-a-table-shorter/84536#84536

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\saved@arstrutbox
\newcommand*{\setarstrut}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \global\setbox\saved@arstrutbox\copy\@arstrutbox
      \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{%
        \vrule \@height #1
               \@depth  0cm
               \@width\z@
      }%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\restorearstrut}{%
  \noalign{%
    \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\copy\saved@arstrutbox
  }%
}
\makeatother

% New command to add an extra custom padding at the top of a row.
% Basically, it adds an empty row with the height value
% defined in the command.

% \paddingtop{height}{content}

\newcommand{\paddingtop}[2]{\setarstrut{#1} #2 \\ \restorearstrut}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{8cm}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|X|} \hline
        \paddingtop{0.2cm}{&&}
        Top Left & Top Middle & Top Right \\[2mm] \hline
        \paddingtop{1.5cm}{&&}
        Middle Left & Middle & Middle Right \\[2mm] \hline
        \paddingtop{5.cm}{&&}
        Bottom Left & Bottom & Bottom Right \\[2mm] \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: I see. I think I will use that for my smaller tables as it seems pretty easy. Question: Why was it necessary to nest the `\tabularx` environment inside the `\table` environment?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Oh, it was not necessary to nest it in a `\table` environment for this example, it was just easier for me to test.  In a document however, using the `\table` environment is useful for automatic placement of your `\tabular`  within the flow of the text.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything I've tried to find a way to address your problem in a way that was more in-line with the spirit of Latex, but failed. I hope some of the very knowledgeable folks here will find a better solution. I would like to know too how to do this.

Comment: The solution you provided will actually work for a lot of what I want to do, so thanks! If there's a better way, though, I hope it comes!

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Just letting you know I've added an alternative solution to my original answer.

Comment: @ Jean-Sébastien Gosselin    Awesome, thank you! I'm going to try that now. I don't understand 95% of the code, but for my purposes, if it works, I'm happy :)