# TabularX Adjustments

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

I'm trying to make a table in `TabularX` to help kids understand fraction and decimal conversions.

Questions:

(1) How do I fix the vertical alignment of the bottom right merged cell?

(2) Is there an easy way to space the five columns evenly?

(3) I used the `\paddingtop` thing to create space between the cell content and the horizontal rules as recommended in an [earlier thread of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257050/row-padding-row-by-row/257103#257103). Is there an easier way to space the content from the horizontal rules? Ideally one that doesn't make the vertical rules extend a bit too far "into" the merged cell.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}

 % Will be my standard column with all contents centered horizontally and vertically.
 \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

 % redefines the final X column as vertically centered.
 \renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

 % Not sure what this does
 \usepackage{cellspace}
 \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{20pt}
 \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

 % Not sure what this does
 \addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

 % The insanely complex stuff for creating the paddingtop part. 
   I would love a simpler way of doing this.
 \makeatletter
 \newsavebox\saved@arstrutbox
 \newcommand*{\setarstrut}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \global\setbox\saved@arstrutbox\copy\@arstrutbox
      \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{%
        \vrule \@height #1
               \@depth  0cm
               \@width\z@
      }%
    \endgroup
  }%
 }
 \newcommand*{\restorearstrut}{%
  \noalign{%
    \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\copy\saved@arstrutbox
  }%
 }
 \makeatother

 % New command to add an extra custom padding at the top of a row.
 % Basically, it adds an empty row with the height value defined in the command.

 % \paddingtop{height}{content, i.e. ampersands}

 \newcommand{\paddingtop}[2]{\setarstrut{#1} #2 \\ \restorearstrut}

% MACRO for basic number line with whole numbers underneath and fractional tick marks. Must be *inside* a tikz environment
\newcommand{\NL}[2] %{xmax}{denom}
{
 \draw (0,0)--(#1,0);
 \pgfmathparse{#1*#2}
 \foreach \x in {0,...,\pgfmathresult}
  \draw (\x/#2,-0.2)--(\x/#2,0.2);
 \foreach \x in {0,...,#1}
  \node[anchor=mid] at (\x,-0.65) {\x};
}


\newcommand{\decimaltable}
{

\begin{tabularx}{23cm}{*4{|C{4.2cm}}|X|} \hline

\paddingtop{0.2cm}{&&&&}

Decimal(s) \vspace{2.5cm} & Mixed Number(s) \vspace{2.5cm} &  Hundredths Only \vspace{2.5cm} & Tenths \& Hundredths \vspace{2.5cm} & Other Denominators \vspace{2.5cm}\\ \hline

\paddingtop{0.2cm}{&&&&}
Price \vspace{2.5cm} & As few L, D and P as possible. \vspace{2.5cm} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Other Coin Denominations}\\ \hline

\end{tabularx}

}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\decimaltable
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabularx` is the wrong tool here really, as the column widths are known in advance. I simplified the markup generally but seems to make the required table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape,array}

\newcommand{\decimaltable}
{{\par
\setlength\extrarowheight{10pt}%
\begin{tabular}{|*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.2cm}|}} \hline
Decimal(s) & 
Mixed Number(s) &  
Hundredths Only  & 
Tenths \& Hundredths & 
Other Denominators \\[2cm] \hline
Price & 
As few L, D and P as possible.& 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Other Coin Denominations}\\[2cm]\hline
\end{tabular}\par
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\decimaltable
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see. Thank you! This looks far better. Next question: Does the `\extrarowheight{10pt}`  of blank space to the top of every cell?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything see array package doc, it adds to the default height of every row.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure if this issue will be mentioned in there, but eventually the document will be merged with other stuff that uses a `tabularx` pakcage. That's one of the reasons I'm using `tabularx` now. Are `array` and `tabularx` compatible?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything `tabularx` is implemented using `array`