# How to make a row in a table have a fixed height

Tags: tables, spacing

Having read the answer in [How to make a row in a table shorter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84524/136923), I have another question: is there any way to make the row's height to be a fixed value (like 0.3cm)?

My table is the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  a & b & c \\
  \hline
  {\tiny a} & {\tiny b} & {\tiny c} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I want the second column to have a height as fixed length, rather than something like `\setarstrut{\tiny}` in Heiko Oberdiek's answer.

Answer (score 2):

a rude hack: add zero wide rule to each cell in the last column (as strut):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c<{\rule[-2mm]{0pt}{7mm}}|}
  \hline
  a & b & c \\
  \hline
  \tiny a & \tiny b & \tiny c \\
  \hline
  a & b & c \\
  \hline
  \tiny a & \tiny b & \tiny c \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

off-topic: `\tiny` is not environment, it is switch from one font size to `tiny` size. so the correct use is `{\tiny a}` or simple `\tiny a` if it use is limited by cell in table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But with your solution, I can onlt make the row to be higher, but can't be lower. Actually, what I hope to do is to make the "tiny" row to be lower, and have a fixed height (1cm may be too large, maybe 5mm?).

Comment: @Stone-Zeng, sorry, this i didn't conclude from your question. from your comment i understand, that you like to have standard table features: cells' heights accommodate to font size. you might consider to determine additional vertical space which can be determined by macros from `makecell` or `cellspace`. please edit your question and clarify what you like to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84536/136923), I finally get the way to change one row' height (and depth):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xparse}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% #1=height, #2=depth. They should be dimexpr.
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \setarstrut { m m }
  { \mytab_set_array_strut:nn {#1} {#2} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \restorearstrut { }
  { \mytab_restore_array_strut: }

\box_new:N \l__mytab_old_arstrut_box

\cs_new:Npn \mytab_set_array_strut:nn #1#2
  {
    \tex_noalign:D
      {
        \group_begin:
          % Store the old strutbox
          \box_gset_eq:NN \l__mytab_old_arstrut_box \@arstrutbox
          % Change the dimension of \@arstrutbox
          \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn \l_tmpa_box { \c_zero_dim } { }
          \box_set_ht:Nn \l_tmpa_box {#1}
          \box_set_dp:Nn \l_tmpa_box {#2}
          \hbox_gset:Nn \@arstrutbox { \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box }
        \group_end:
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \mytab_restore_array_strut:
  {
    \tex_noalign:D
      { \box_gset_eq:NN \@arstrutbox \l__mytab_old_arstrut_box }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  a & b & c \\
  \hline
  \setarstrut{4pt}{1.3pt}
  \tiny a & \tiny b & \tiny c \\
  \restorearstrut
  \hline
  a & b & c \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I use LaTeX3 to rewrite the code, but the main idea is the same: just to modify the box `\@arstrutbox`.

Result:

[image]