# Setting the vertical height of a row that uses `diagbox`

Tags: tables, vertical-spacing, height, diagbox

I am trying to set the vertical height of a row which uses `diagbox` to be smaller, but past techniques such as [`\setarstrut`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409485/how-to-make-a-row-in-a-table-have-a-fixed-height) and [`cellspace`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511651/adjust-backslashbox-to-a-different-arraystretch-row-too-high) appear to not be working thus far. In particular, I am able to almost create the table exactly as sought, but the the row with the diagonal is too tall. How exactly can one set this particular row to be a constant height (e.g. to match the height of the other rows)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{0.8cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{1.1cm}| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Table} \\
 \hline
 \backslashbox{$P_1$\kern-1em}{\kern-1em$P_2$} & $10$ & $50$ & $100$ &$500$ &$1000$ &$5000$\\
 \hline
 $10$ & 0.0238 & 0.0238  & 0.0087 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238
\\
\hline
 $50$ & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238
\\
\hline
 $100$ & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238
\\
\hline
 $500$ & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0065 & 0.0081 & 0.0083 & 0.0129
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table]

Comment: Not related: You don't need to put `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` any longer with recent versions of LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environement `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a built-in command `\diagbox` which gives directly the expected output. Moreover, you have a key `hvlines` which draws all the rules excepted in the blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{0.8cm}*{6}{p{1.1cm}}}[hvlines]
 \Block{1-7}{Table} \\
 \diagbox{$P_1$}{$P_2$} & $10$ & $50$ & $100$ &$500$ &$1000$ &$5000$\\
 $10$ & 0.0238 & 0.0238  & 0.0087 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 \\
 $50$ & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 \\
 $100$ & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 \\
 $500$ & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0065 & 0.0081 & 0.0083 & 0.0129 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

However, you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Works great! As a follow-up, is there a recommended way to centre the text in each cell?

Comment: To center the text in each cell, you can use the type `c` for the columns (the columns will have their natural width). If you want to fix yourself, the width, you can use the type `w`: `w{c}{1cm}` for a column of width 1 cm (with content centered).

Answer (score 1):

The `\diagbox` command can take a height parameter as its input. For example: `\diagbox[height=1cm]{$P_1$}{$P_2$}`

Answer (score 0):

Replace column type in the first column to `c`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{ |c| *{6}{S[table-format=1.4]|} }
    \hline
 \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Table} \\
    \hline
\backslashbox{$P_1$\kern-1em}{\kern-1em$P_2$} 
        & {10}   & {50}     & {100}  & {500}  & {1000} & {5000}     \\
    \hline
 10     & 0.0238 & 0.0238   & 0.0087 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238     \\
    \hline
 50     & 0.0238 & 0.0238   & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238     \\
    \hline
 100    & 0.0238 & 0.0238   & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238     \\
    \hline
 500    & 0.0238 & 0.0238   & 0.0065 & 0.0081 & 0.0083 & 0.0129     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
But, your table I would rather write as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\lineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption*{Table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.0]
           *{6}{S[table-format=1.4]} }
    \toprule
{\multirow{2.2}{*}{$P_1$}}
        &   \multicolumn{6}{c}{$P_2$} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-7}
        & {10}   & {50}     & {100}  & {500}  & {1000} & {5000}     \\
    \midrule
 10     & 0.0238 & 0.0238   & 0.0087 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238     \\
 50     & 0.0238 & 0.0238   & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238     \\
    \addlinespace
 100    & 0.0238 & 0.0238   & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238 & 0.0238     \\
 500    & 0.0238 & 0.0238   & 0.0065 & 0.0081 & 0.0083 & 0.0129     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]