# How to guess and use the height of a tabular row

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, height

As a pure challenge, I try to draw hugly top tabular column. I have almost done, still a poblem to control there height.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array,tabularx,tikz,ragged2e,siunitx,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}

% 3 couches de dessin
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RowHeight}{% see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84536/121799
\def\tmp{\dimexpr\arraystretch\ht\strutbox+\arraystretch\ht\strutbox+\arraystretch\dp\@arstrutbox}\relax
\xdef\myrowheight{\the\tmp}\relax
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\Daube}{sms}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base),overlay]
        \node[text depth=0pt,text height=1ex,
            minimum height=\myrowheight,
            minimum width=2cm+2\tabcolsep]
            (A) {\textbf{\textsf{#2}}};
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw[fill=blue!15,draw=white,line width=2\arrayrulewidth]
        \IfBooleanT{#1}{[rounded corners=12pt]}
            ([yshift=2.5\arrayrulewidth]A.south west)
         -- ([yshift=2\arrayrulewidth]A.north west)
        \IfBooleanT{#1}{[rounded corners=0pt]}
        \IfBooleanT{#3}{[rounded corners=12pt]}
        -- ([yshift=2\arrayrulewidth]A.north east)
        \IfBooleanT{#3}{[rounded corners=0pt]}
        -- ([yshift=2.5\arrayrulewidth]A.south east) -- cycle ;
        \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
    X*{3}{>{\Centering}m{2cm}}}
Entourer la ou les bonne(s) reponse(s)\RowHeight
& \Daube*{a}
& \Daube{b}
& \Daube{p}*
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}}

\bigskip

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
    X*{3}{>{\Centering}m{2cm}}}
Entourer la reponse\RowHeight
& \Daube*{a}
& \Daube{b}
& \Daube{p}*
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, as I said in my previous answer, I had to put in by hand that there is a column that extends over two rows. That's why I put `\arraystretch\ht\strutbox+\arraystretch\ht\strutbox` instead of `\arraystretch\ht\strutbox` in the `\RowHeight` command. So that is the technical reason why things don't work out in your command, I think. Anyway, it will be interesting to see if someone can answer the question (+1).

Comment: Is there a way to know how many lines are in the first table cell? If yes, you can put `\dimexpr\arraystretch\ht\strutbox*`<line number>`+\arraystretch\dp\@arstrutbox` ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht Well, it's not that I haven't thought about this. But even if there is a way, you're not done, simply because some line could contain some large object such as $\displaystyle\int_a^b\dots$.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Generally one or two lines of normal text to say how to tick the boxes, even empty. But the idea is to have a general \RowHeight that can be used in other places.

Comment: Could you please check: I think your code does no longer compile after you have switched to `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: @marmot Sorry, paste in the wrong way.

Comment: You may also have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110352/121799). I believe this achieves what you want.

Comment: Actually, since X behaves like a \parbox[t], the height of the parbox is less than \araystretch\ht\strutbox, but the depth far exceeds \arraystretch\dp\strutbox.  The parbox itself is USUALLY \normalbaselineskip times the number of lines.  It helps to throw in a \strut at the begining and end of the \parbox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

like this:?

[image]

**edit:**
the code is combination of `tabularx` and `tikz`, as you desired :-).  now is corrected on the way that are considered all improvements of solution in the addendum,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\DL}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]
    \node[minimum width=\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep,
          minimum height=12mm, text depth=0.25ex,
          inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=0pt,
       append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \path[draw=white, thick, fill=blue!15]
        (\LN.south west) -| (\LN.north east)
            {[rounded corners=6mm] -- (\LN.north west)} -- cycle;
       \path[draw=blue!15, thick, 
             shorten <=0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >=0.5\pgflinewidth]       
        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east);
                       }     },
        font=\bfseries] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}   }
\newcommand{\DC}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]
    \node[minimum width=\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep,
          minimum height=12mm, text depth=0.25ex,
          inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=0pt,
          append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \path[draw=white, thick, fill=blue!15]
        (\LN.south west) -| (\LN.north east) -| cycle;
       \path[draw=blue!15, thick, 
             shorten <=0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >=0.5\pgflinewidth]
        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east);
                      }     },
          font=\bfseries] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
\newcommand{\DR}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]
    \node[minimum width=\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep,
          minimum height=12mm, text depth=0.25ex,
          inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=0pt,
       append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \path[draw=white, thick, fill=blue!15]
        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east)
            {[rounded corners=6mm] -- (\LN.north east)} -| cycle;
       \path[draw=blue!15, thick,
             shorten <=0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >=0.5\pgflinewidth]
        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east);
                       }     },
        font=\bfseries] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
    >{\raggedright}X *{3}{@{}>{\Centering}m{\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep}@{}}
                            }
Entourer la ou les bonne(s) reponse(s)
    & \DL{a}    & \DC{b}    & \DR{p}    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
    >{\raggedright}X*{3}{@{}>{\Centering}m{\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep}@{}}
                            }
Entourer la reponse
    & \DL{a}    & \DC{b}    & \DR{p}    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

if you like adopt tizz picture height to height of text in the first column, i don't know for automatic solution. however codes in command can be extend so that nodes height can be change in advance ad each its use (now is set to 12mm).

**addedndum:**
meanwhile  i made new solution which automatically adopt heights of  `tikz` nodes to height of the first cell in the first table's column. calculation is based on measurement of the first  cell content height. obtained result is:

[image]

mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}

% commands \DaubeL, \DaubeL, \DaubeL are renamed for
% shorter writing to \DL, \DC and \DR
% all commands recoded (simplified) and adopted
% to automatic determination of tikz node heights
\newcommand{\DL}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]
    \node[minimum width=\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep,
          minimum height=#1,  text depth=0.25ex,
          inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=0pt,
       append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \path[draw=white, thick, fill=blue!15]
        (\LN.south west) -| (\LN.north east)
            {[rounded corners=\CH/2] -- (\LN.north west)} -- cycle;
       \path[draw=blue!15, thick, shorten <=0.5\pgflinewidth]
        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east);
                       }     },
        font=\bfseries] {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}   }
\newcommand{\DC}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]
    \node[minimum width=\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep,
      minimum height=#1, text depth=0.25ex,
      inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=0pt,
          append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \path[draw=white, thick, fill=blue!15]
        (\LN.south west) -| (\LN.north east) -| cycle;
       \path[draw=blue!15, thick, shorten <=0.5\pgflinewidth]
        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east);
                      }     },
          font=\bfseries] {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
\newcommand{\DR}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]
    \node[minimum width=\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep,
          minimum height=#1, text depth=0.25ex,
          inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=0pt,
       append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \path[draw=white, thick, fill=blue!15]
        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east)
            {[rounded corners=\CH/2] -- (\LN.north east)} -| cycle;
       \path[draw=blue!15, thick, 
                 shorten <=0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >=0.5\pgflinewidth]
        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east);
                       }     },
        font=\bfseries] {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}}

% command for calculation of height of first cel in the first column
% by experiments is determined minimum height: 1.7\baselineskip
\newcommand\firstcell[1]{
\sbox\cellbox{\parbox{\FC}{\raggedright #1}}
\pgfmathparse{max(8mm,\dimexpr\ht\cellbox+2\dp\cellbox)}
\setlength\CH{\pgfmathresult pt}
                        }
% boxes and length needed in automatic calculation
% of tikz nodes and for shortcut for first column width
\newsavebox\cellbox
\newlength{\CH}% CellHight
\newlength{\FC}% FirstColumn width
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\FC{\dimexpr\linewidth-6cm-6\tabcolsep\relax}
\firstcell{Entourer la ou les bonne(s) reponse(s)}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
    X*{3}{@{}>{\Centering}m{\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep}@{}}
                            }
\usebox\cellbox
    & \DL{\CH}{a}   & \DC{\CH}{b}   & \DR{\CH}{p}    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\firstcell{Entourer la reponse}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
   X*{3}{@{}>{\Centering}m{\dimexpr2cm+2\tabcolsep}@{}}
                            }
\usebox\cellbox
    & \DL{\CH}{a}   & \DC{\CH}{b}   & \DR{\CH}{p}    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

basic description of all changes of (heavily changed) of the first solution are described in mwe code.