# multicolumn with trailing cell separator in NiceTabular

Tags: tables, nicematrix

For a variety of reasons, I migrate some `tabular`s to `NiceTabular`. One of them looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\saved@arstrutbox
\newcommand*{\setarstrut}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \global\setbox\saved@arstrutbox\copy\@arstrutbox
      #1%
      \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{%
        \vrule \@height\arraystretch\ht\strutbox
               \@depth\arraystretch \dp\strutbox
               \@width\z@
      }%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\restorearstrut}{%
  \noalign{%
    \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\copy\saved@arstrutbox
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{c@{/}c}
    \setarstrut{\tiny}
    \multicolumn{1}{c@{\tiny/}}{\tiny\textbf{droggel}} & \tiny\textbf{jug} \\ \restorearstrut \hline
    23 & 42
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The header is mostly taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84536/11150) about making rows smaller. What I do is that I render the first row smaller than the others. Since I use the separator character `/` between the columns, that should also be rendered smaller. To facilitate this, I add a `\multicolumn` that replaces the original separator with a tiny one.

Now I switch out `tabular` with `NiceTabular`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\saved@arstrutbox
\newcommand*{\setarstrut}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \global\setbox\saved@arstrutbox\copy\@arstrutbox
      #1%
      \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{%
        \vrule \@height\arraystretch\ht\strutbox
               \@depth\arraystretch \dp\strutbox
               \@width\z@
      }%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\restorearstrut}{%
  \noalign{%
    \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\copy\saved@arstrutbox
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{c@{/}c}
    \setarstrut{\tiny}
    \multicolumn{1}{c@{\tiny/}}{\tiny\textbf{droggel}} & \tiny\textbf{jug} \\ \restorearstrut \hline
    23 & 42
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this yields:

```
! Package array Error: Empty preamble: `l' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.29 ...column{1}{c@{\tiny/}}{\tiny\textbf{droggel}}
                                                   & \tiny\textbf{jug} \\ \r...
```

The error comes from the `@{\tiny/}` bit of the multicolumn argument. If I delete this, the code renders but the `/` is obviously gone.

How can I migrate this properly to NiceTabular while keeping the separator setup?

Comment: Your example code can be simplified/ shortened quite  abit. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{cl}
    \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{text} & text \\
    text & text
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}` for example still reproduces the error message you also get from your code.

Comment: @leandriis Yeah I wanted to show some context so that someone can suggest a different approach to get what I want since I don't know the possibilities of NiceTabular that well.

Comment: (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). This is a problem of `nicematrix`. `nicematrix` is not compatible with all the types of format of `\multicolumn`. I should mention that problem in the documentation. Maybe, it will be solved in a future version. In your case, I would try to use a tabular with 3 columns (one for the `/`)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a new version of `nicematrix` (v 5.17 of 2021-07-01). With that new version, the command `\multicolumn` should work as expected in the environments of `nicematrix` such as `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\saved@arstrutbox
\newcommand*{\setarstrut}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \global\setbox\saved@arstrutbox\copy\@arstrutbox
      #1%
      \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{%
        \vrule \@height\arraystretch\ht\strutbox
               \@depth\arraystretch \dp\strutbox
               \@width\z@
      }%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\restorearstrut}{%
  \noalign{%
    \global\setbox\@arstrutbox\copy\saved@arstrutbox
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{c@{/}c}
    \setarstrut{\tiny}
    \multicolumn{1}{c@{\tiny/}}{\tiny\textbf{droggel}} & \tiny\textbf{jug} \\ \restorearstrut \hline
    23 & 42
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: With this version of `nicematrix`, having a tabular inside a `\multicolumn` in a `NiceTabular` creates an error while the previous version was able to process it (test code: `\begin{NiceTabular}{p{5cm}}\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}} foo \end{tabular}}\end{NiceTabular}`).

Comment: @flyx: You're right. I have corrected that bug and I will post a new version of `nicematrix` on CTAN. However, if you want, I could sent you that new version and you could test it on your data (my email is on the documentation of `nicematrix`).

Comment: Thanks! I am pretty content that my input will be fine once the code fragment I showed works again, since I narrowed down the error source to that particular structure; everything else works.

Comment: @flyx: Perfect! I will post this new version on CTAN.